# Google Cast Video Player becomes unresponsive after network error

Tags: google-cast, custom-receiver

I am working on a Chromecast custom receiver app, built on top of the sample app provided by Google (`sampleplayer.CastPlayer`)

The app manages a playlist, I would like the player to move on to the next item in the list after a video fails to play for whatever reason.

I am running into a situation where, after a video fails to load because of a network error, the player becomes unresponsive: in the 'onError_()' handler, my custom code will do this

```
var queueLoadRequest = ...
var mediaManager = ...
setTimeout (function(){mediaManager.queueLoad(queueLoadRequest)}), 5000
```

...the player does receive the `LOAD` event according to the receiver logs, but nothing happens on the screen, the player's status remains `IDLE`and the `mediaManager.getMediaQueue().getItems()` remains `undefined`. Same result trying to use the client controller to try to load a different video.

I have tried to recover with `mediaManager.resetMediaElement()` and `player.reset()` in the `onError_` handler, but no luck.

For reference, here is a screenshot of the logs (filtered for errors only) leading up to the player becoming unresponsive. Note that I am not interested in fixing the original error, what I need to figure out is how to recover from it:

[image]

My custom code is most likely responsible for the issue, however after spending many hours + stripping the custom code to a bare minimum in an effort to isolate the responsible bit of code, I have not made any progress. I am not looking for a fix but rather for some guidance in troubleshooting the root cause: ***what could possibly cause the Player to become unresponsive?*** or alternatively ***how can one recover from an unresponsive Player?***

Comment: You may refer with this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com) which stated that the website does not allow you to access the resources. You should check the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) that restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious documents.

Comment: Thanks @abielita, I am aware of cross-origin restrictions.The original error isn't the issue, my question is "how does one recover after the player becomes unresponsive" - the fact that the player becomes unresponsive after a network error is secondary.